# How to update record with edit form?

Tags: symfony

I Have this code, that must update object in DB with data from form, but it says that i must  use setId() instead of direct changind property "ID". But i need to get "ID" from hiding field from previous form. How can i get that works?

```
        $rPhone = new RejectedPhone();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository("TelnetSmsBundle:RejectedPhone");

        $addRPhoneForm = $this->createFormBuilder($rPhone)
                ->add('id', 'hidden')
                ->add('phone', 'text', array("label" => "Номер телефона (обязательно через 7-ку!):"))
                ->add('description', 'textarea', array("label" => "Описание:"))
                ->getForm();

        $addRPhoneForm->bindRequest($request);

        var_dump($rPhone); exit();

        $em->flush();
```

Comment: Ok, i add SetId() to my Entity's class, error dissapear, but it still don't upgrade record

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
$addRPhoneForm ->setData($rPhone);
```

I think you forgot  the persist method:

```
$em->persist($rPhone);
```